# get the address of a function (without interfacing C)

Tags: haskell, binary, ghc, ffi

Having a rather low level application, I came into a sitatuion where I needed to determine the address of a Haskell function. I was able to do that with FFI, that is C, but I would like to do it directly in Haskell.

Here is my current solution with FFI:

main.hs:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}
module Main where

import Foreign
import Foreign.C.Types
import Text.Printf

foreign import ccall "getFuncAddr"
  getFuncAddr :: CULong

main :: IO ()
main = do
  printf "0x%016x\n" (fromIntegral getFuncAddr :: Word64)

foreign export ccall func :: IO ()
func :: IO ()
func = do
  printf "hello world\n"
```

ffi.c:

```
void func(void);

unsigned long getFuncAddr(void)
{
    return (unsigned long) func;
}
```

Makefile:

```
all: main
    ./$<
    objdump -D $< | grep '<func>'

main: main.hs ffi.c
    ghc --make -O2 $^ -o $@
```

as always, also available as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/2904609).

Comment: Would probably help if you explain _why_ you need the address; perhaps there's a better way?

Comment: I'm generating code with [harpy](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/harpy) at runtime. From that generated code, I would like to jump to a haskell function (in that case, for allocating memory), therefore I need the address and provide it the `call` instruction.

Comment: FWIW, it's not guaranteed that a pointer fits in an `unsigned long` on all platforms. You should either use `void *` instead, or, if you want to be really explicit probably use `ptrdiff_t` from `stddef.h`.

Comment: @dflemstr: Shouldn't that be `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t`?  `ptrdiff_t` is for the difference of two pointers, which could be smaller than a full pointer on some odd architecture.

Comment: @AntalS-Z, yes, you're probably right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}
module Main where

import Foreign
import Foreign.C.Types
import Text.Printf

foreign import ccall "&func"
  funcaddr :: FunPtr (IO ())

main :: IO ()
main = do
  printf "0x%016x\n" (fromIntegral (ptrToIntPtr (castFunPtrToPtr funcaddr)) :: Int)

foreign export ccall func :: IO ()
func :: IO ()
func = do
  printf "hello world\n"
```

See [this section of the Haskell 2010 report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch8.html#x15-1610008.5), and look for "Static Addresses."

Answer (score 2):

I think the documentation for [FunPtr](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.5.0.0/doc/html/Foreign-Ptr.html#t%3aFunPtr) has pretty much what you want. The short version is you use `foreign import "wrapper"`, as follows:

```
foreign import ccall "wrapper"
  getFuncAddr :: IO () -> IO (FunPtr (IO ()))
```

and then if you're done with it later, use [`freeHaskellFunPtr`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.5.0.0/doc/html/Foreign-Ptr.html#v%3afreeHaskellFunPtr).

Comment: that looks like the right direction, however I'm not able to obtain the address of `func` with it. The `Addr#` value of `FunPtr` doesn't match with the actual value of `func` (probably I'm doing something wrong). Could you provide a working example please?

Comment: Hmm, tricky. I'm not sure I can provide a working example without doing a fair bit more work :P did you try calling it anyway? I suspect the pointer you get is a pointer to a function which calls the function you actually want, perhaps to handle marshalling or whatever.

Comment: well, I don't want to call it, I want the address.

Comment: @lewurm: I meant, providing it to the `call` instruction, which is what you indicated you wanted to do in the other comments. If you have other requirements, then this technique probably won't work for you.

Comment: oh, sorry :-( I didn't get that in the first place. You're actually right, this looks **very** promising, although I don't get it to work right now. Probably I'm doing something wrong; no time atm, I'll investigate it tomorrow. thanks!

Comment: using @Simon Marlows's approch (see his answer), it works great using `FunPtr` and `call`.